# Cocoalumberjack send warn/error logs to sentry

Tags: ios, logging, sentry, cocoalumberjack

I want to do logging into my existing project. I want to know that If I add cocoalumberjack for logging how do I send warning logs and error logs automatically to sentry or firebase or any third party framework ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a sentry integration with Cocoalumberjack.

https://github.com/bruno-garcia/SentryCocoaLumberjack

Full disclosure: I'm the author.

Comment: I saw the code it's not compatible with Obj-C. Can you make it compatible with Objective-C ?

Comment: Also do you know any android alternatives for the same ?

Comment: you can use Timber and the Sentry Android SDK
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/integrations/timber/

Comment: The code in it is super simple and can be easily ported to Obj-C. It's basically this 1 file: https://github.com/bruno-garcia/SentryCocoaLumberjack/blob/main/Sources/SentryCocoaLumberjack/SentryLogger.swift#L4

Comment: You can use the latest version of `sentry-cocoa` and in there you can already improve on what I did, see the TODO: I have: https://github.com/bruno-garcia/SentryCocoaLumberjack/blob/main/Sources/SentryCocoaLumberjack/SentryLogger.swift#L72-L73 it can now be resolved, because there's now SentryMessage: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cocoa/blob/master/Sources/Sentry/Public/SentryEvent.h#L22